# How to create dynamic directory structure on SD card in Android?

Tags: android, file, directory, creation

I want to create directories automatically on my SDCard with given path which contains complete path for a file. the path is coming dynamically from a server so I don't know what are the names of the directories are and how many deep is the directory structure is.

e.g. dir1/dir2/dir3/file1.txt

I am using the following piece of code

```
createDirectoryIfNotPresent(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/"+ mypaths.getNextPath());
```

where definition of

```
createDirectoryIfNotPresent
```

is

```
private void createDirectoryIfNotPresent(String fileName) {
    File f = new File(fileName);

    if(!f.exists())
        f.mkdirs();
}
```

but the above code creates directory for file1.txt as well. How do I avoid this? I just want to create directories for directory names and not for filenames.

Comment: How about splitting the string, with the last / as splitting mark?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something as simple as check if the filename contains .txt or other extensions

```
if(f.toString.contains(".txt")) {
f.createNewFile();
} else {
f.mkdirs();
}
```

If the extensions keep changing, you might even resort to using regular expressions.

Comment: I dont even know the extension of the file.

Comment: Ok, so basically any file has to be in the format name.extension You can use regular expression to see if the input name matches it. If yes, create a file, else go for a Directory. Refer this link for more info on regex http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html